# Format for a multiple Replace Commands

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, shell

Lets say i have this in a shell

```
"chdir * && whoami.exe >> $$$"
```

I have this replacecommand

```
Dim ReplaceCommand as String = sCommand.Replace("*", UserDirect)
```

I also would like the $$$ to be replaced with a user chosen filepath.
I can get the file path chosen but it never puts it into the shell.

I have tried

```
Dim ReplaceCommand1, ReplaceCommand2 as String = sCommand.Replace("*" & "$$$", UserDirect & filepath)
Shell("cmd.exe" & ReplaceCommand1 & ReplaceCommand2)

Dim ReplaceCommand as String = sCommand.Replace("*", UserDirect) & ("$$$", filepath)
Shell("cmd.exe" & ReplaceCommand)
```

also

```
Dim ReplaceCommand1 as String = sCommand.Replace("*", UserDirect)
Dim ReplaceCommand2 as String = sCommand.Replace("$$$", filepath)
Shell("cmd.exe" & ReplaceCommand1 & ReplaceCommand2)
```

EDIT:
get a path to short error when I use commas in shell instead of &

```
Dim ReplaceCommand1 as String = sCommand.Replace("*", UserDirect)
Dim ReplaceCommand2 as String = sCommand.Replace("$$$", filepath)
Shell("cmd.exe", ReplaceCommand1 , ReplaceCommand2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can chain the Replace's together:

```
Dim ReplaceCommand1 as String = sCommand.Replace("*", UserDirect).Replace("$$$", filepath)
Shell("cmd.exe" & ReplaceCommand1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Part of your examples don't compile cause of the syntax errors.

You're not using Shell() like you're supposed to.

```
Public Function Shell(
    PathName As String,
    Optional Style As Microsoft.VisualBasic.AppWinStyle = MinimizedFocus,
    Optional Wait As Boolean = False,
    Optional Timeout As Integer = -1
) As Integer
```

From the examples you gave, it looks like you're just throwing stuff together. Stop and think for a minute :)

Comment: the shells runs perfectly, until I go and want to add multiple replacements in a line :(

Comment: I was referring to the part you edited in, using commas instead of &.